# How to auto-fill a new point vector in a vector layer?

Tags: qgis, vector, point

When I work *in-situ* I manually add points in my shape-file. I would like that when I add a new point some attributes would already filled with values calculated programmatically. E.g in my first column a progressive number (first point automatically add `1`, second `2` etc. etc.) like an auto `$rownum` second column **id of the instrument measure** usually is something like `$rownum+n`where `n`is a number. I'm able to to that only in post processing with the command I've mentioned but for me would be very helpful have a quick look to labeled point when I'm taking them.So is there a way to pre-fill determinate values of a new point vector?

Comment: If you can migrate your shapefile to a spatialite database, then you can define an attribute column as INTEGER AUTONUMBER, and you have a automatically incrementing column. You can also set default values for other columns.